# Vbscript doesn't output file

Tags: vbscript

Here's what I have.  Why is it not exporting the file at all?  If I remove the "sdate" part of the Set NewFile line it works fine.

```
On Error Resume Next
  Dim fso, folder, files, sFolder, sDate

  sDate = Date

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  sFolder = "\\mypath" 'Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
  If sFolder = "" Then
      Wscript.Echo "No Folder parameter was passed"
      Wscript.Quit
  End If
  Set NewFile = fso.CreateTextFile(sFolder& "\Refunds" & sDate & ".csv", True)
  Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
  Set files = folder.Files

  For each folderIdx In files
    NewFile.WriteLine(Replace(Replace(folderIdx.Name,"_",","), ".pdf",""))(folderIdx.Name)
   Next
  NewFile.Close

x=msgbox("CSV list complete." ,0, "Done")
```

Comment: Remove the EVIL global OERN, test again, publish problems if need be.

Comment: It says "Path not found" - but it does output just fine without the "sDate" in there.

Comment: Probably, because there is no folder named to the current date. Furthermore, the NewFile.WriteLine line should throw another error.

Comment: Well the ultimate goal here is to add the date to the file name.  What way should I go about it to make it work?

Comment: Create the folder if it doesn't exists?

Comment: I just want it to output a file that says Refunds 4-7-2015.csv    (or whatever date it is that day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line

```
sDate = Date
```

with

```
sDate = Replace(Date, "/", "-")
```

Also to be sure your script will work on PCs having another language settings add the line at the beginning

```
SetLocale(1033)
```